# run a script as non-root user

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I want to run a script say `some_script.sh`(that requires root permissions, contains some `sudo do something` in a for loop) as non-root user. I have a script as shown below. I want to run this script as root and using this I want to run the other one `some_script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    if [ some conditioon ] 
    then
        sudo some_script.sh &
        sleep 30
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

#### Note

- `some_script.sh` is in PATH and I want that to go on checking at each 30 sec
- It is executing smoothly if I run `some_script.sh` from terminal as `sudo some_script.sh`, when I am going to run it using above script it is doing its job partially.

---

Is it possible to do like this?  if yes then what are the problems above, show me any better way.

#### Edit

please take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375545/convey-some-message-to-all-users/380180#380180). Please read `some_script.sh` as `msgpass.sh` of that answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the big picture? What is `some_script.sh` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the script to run as root every 30 minutes, use cron.

Edit the file /etc/crontab to contain the following:

```
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    user    command
*/30    *       *       *       *       root    some_script.sh
```